# script on a folder containing multiple datasets,every dataset in that folder retrieve a list of the field names and corresponding dataset

Tags: python

This is the path to the folder containing 6 csv files

```
path = r'/Users/username/Documents/Lab/Datasets/FDA_Dataset'
```

All six files are then globbed into `FDA_dataset((dataset_melanoma, datset_prostate, dataset_ovarian, dataset_lung, dataset_colorectal, and dataset_breast)`

```
FDA_dataset = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
```

I defined a function to create a `dataframe` for each csv file (6 dataframes) and return field names and their corresponding dataset.

For example, I want to return:

```
field_1, dataset_melanoma
field_2, dataset_melanoma
field_3, dataset_melanoma
...
field_1, dataset_breast
field_2, dataset_breast
field_3, dataset_breast
```

This is my function:

```
def parse_csv(filename):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
        for col in df.columns:
                print(col, '\n,', filename)
for x in FDA_dataset:
        print(parse_csv(x))
```

This returns: field, file path

However, I want to return the field and file name (rather the file path) as such:

```
field#, dataset_cancer.
```

How can I call the variable `'filename'` in the defining function as the file name (without extension) rather than the file path?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. Better show example data and expected result.

Comment: `filename` is a string so you can use string functions to edit it - ie. `split("/")`, `split(".")`, `replace(".csv". "")`, `filename[:-4]` to skip extension. You can also use module `os.path` like `os.path.basename(...)` or `os.path.split(...)` or `os.path.splitext(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Paths is string so you can use string functions to work with this: ie. `path.split('.')`, `path.split('/')`, `path[:-4]`, `path.replace('.csv', '')`

```
path = r'/Users/username/Documents/Lab/Datasets/FDA_Dataset/dataset_cancer.csv'

print( path.split('.')[0].rsplit('/', 1)[1] )
```

Result:

```
dataset_cancer
```

You can also use module `os.path`: ie. `os.path.basename(...)` or `os.path.split(...)` or `os.path.splitext(...)`

```
import os.path

print( os.path.splitext(os.path.split(path)[-1])[0] )

print( os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0] )
```

Result:

```
dataset_cancer
```

You can also mix both

```
print( os.path.basename(path)[:-4] )

print( os.path.basename(path).split('.')[0] )

print( os.path.basename(path).replace('.csv', '') )
```